# Continuity on the boundary of analytic map does not allow the assumption of specific values in the interior

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I have the following problem: Let $G$ be a domain in the upper half plane such that $\partial G\cap\mathbb{R}$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. a disjoint union of open intervals. Suppose that $f:G\cup(\partial G\cap\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{C}$ is a continuous and injective function, holomorphic on $G$ and such that $f(z)\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{R}\cap\partial G$. My question is this: Is it possible that $f$ assumes a real value on $G$? I believe no, but I cannot prove this.

I was thinking of possible ways to apply the maximum modulus principle for harmonic functions on the real or imaginary part, but I have no information on the rest of the boundary of $G$. Moreover I don't see how to take advantage of the injectivity of $f$;

Another idea that might help would be to extend $f$ to a holomorphic function defined on the domain $G\cup(\mathbb{R}\cap \partial G)\cup G^*$ (this is readily seen to be a domain) (where $^*$ denotes image under complex conjugation) by the Riemann-Schwarz reflection principle. Then again, I don't see why this new setting would help me rule out the possibility of $f$ assuming real values on interior points (note that $f_1(z)=\bar{f}(\bar{z})$ where $f_1$ is the extention)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $f$ can assume a real value on $G$. Suppose that $G=\left\{re^{i\theta}\,\middle|\,r\in(0,\infty)\wedge\theta\in\left(0,\frac{2\pi}3\right)\right\}$ and that $f(z)=z^2$. Then $\delta G\cap\mathbb R=(0,\infty)$, which is an open subset of $\mathbb R$, and $f$ is injective. But $i\in G$ and $f(i)=-1\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: and if we extend this function by setting $f_1(z)=z^2$ on the set $G\cup(0,\infty)\cup G^*$ then this is still holomorphic, injective on both sets $G\cup(0,\infty)$ and $G^*\cup(0,\infty)$ but not injective in the whole domain, right? (e.g. $f_1(i)=f_1(-i)=-1$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Okay, then. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Well ... $\partial G \cap \mathbb R$ has to be a closed subset of $\mathbb R.$ The statement of the problem should be changed to reflect this.